# SSRS outputting multiple instances of a report with one dataset, iterating on document level

Tags: reporting-services

I have a process that outputs multiple instances of the same report. Something like packing-slips for instance. Right now it is relatively slow because the whole process is done for each iteration. Creating the data calling the ssrs report, output it clean-up the report instance and data and start again. It has a lot of overhead and unnecessary repetition.

An idea i have is to create all the data beforehand and add a document number to the dataset so to differentiate between documents. And call the ssrs report 1 time to output all the documents contained in 1 big document. So all the documents separate with their own header and footer but created in 1 go and in 1 file.

The thing i am looking for is to iterate on document level.

Is something like this possible with ssrs?

---

I have been googling and is it something i could solve with sub reports?

Comment: You can use subreports but this won;t really solve your problem as the subreport will have to run the query each time. You would be better to group your main report by some unique identifier (document ID/number?) and set a page break between each instance of the group. The query would only execute once this way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea i will look into it. 

It is not really a problem if the sub-report makes multiple queries to the database. As long as the calling application is free of the load and is free to be used by the user. The whole aim is to move and reduce the load off of the user application and into the MSSQL/SSRS servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with SSRS. The way I usually go about this style of a report is to first create a table with a single cell in it. Set the row to be grouped by document ID. Set the group to page break between instances. Now place a large rectangle inside the cell. Place all the elements you want to have on each page inside the rectangle. Note that you would not use actual headers and footers, just textboxes, tables, etc. No sub-reports needed.

Now when you run the report, you will get one copy of the entire layout per page and each page is naturally filtered to the containing document ID. Since you are letting the report split up the data for you, you can let your dataset be one large query instead of many smaller ones. This will drastically improve your efficiency.